# Circular Imports issue with Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, circular-dependency

I am trying to re-work a Selenium / Python script but hitting a wall regarding circular imports (*partially initialized module 'x' has no attribute 'y' (most likely due to a circular import)*).

I read up on a bunch of other questions here, yet I was not able to figure out an answer from any of them. Basically, say there are two scripts, main.py and first_site.py I want to do as follows:

main.py:

```
def click_from_xpath(name, xpath):       #...or any other Selenium action
    clicker = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    )
    clicker.click()
```

first_site.py:

```
def first_site_navigation():     
    main.click_from_xpath('name1','xpath1')
    main.click_from_xpath('name2','xpath2')
```

Then, main.py:

```
first_site.first_site_navigation()
```

I want to tick these three boxes:

1. In *main.py*, **I define the actions I want to run with Selenium as functions**.
2. In *first_site.py*, **I define a single function that calls all the functions defined in main.py in a specific order**. I want to do this as I wish to add more sites (second_site, third_site etc.) with a different set of instructions, but don't want these to all be within the same script.
3. In *main.py*, **I want to call the single function which executes all the site navigation for first_site** so that the main file stays short and concise. And then do the same for second_site, etc.

I tried playing around for hours with importing main.py inside first_site.py and vice versa, but I keep getting errors. Also a bit overwhelmed by the other, more theoretical answers on the site. Would anyone be able to suggest a good solution for this issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `name` of the file is not the `same` as the `module` you are `importing` – this will make Python think there is a circular dependency.

Check out this : https://www.pythonpool.com/python-circular-import/

Comment: Thank you, I don't believe this is the issue though, as I am not using any modules named the same as the files!